# HBase export snapshot to another cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to export my hbase table snapshot to another cluster in different datacenter. I am wondering are the exportSnapshot tool guarantees security, or I need to care of it by myself?
I am using:

```
hbase class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot MySnapshot -copy-to hdfs://mydestination:8082/hbase -mappers xxx
```

in this case which kind of connection will be established between source cluster and `hdfs://mydestination:8082/hbase`?